# 2D array in java gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and i am using eclipse for its compilation. I have seen many forums but i am not able to get around this error. I am creating a program for my homework and this is a small section of that program which is giving weird error. Any help is appreciated.

Here is where i am getting error -> `aTwoD[i][j] = 0; <- at Initialize2D.<init>(Initialize2D.java:19)`

I am stuck on this for quite some time now. 
:-(

What is did ->

```
public class Initialize2D
{
    private int[][] aTwoD;

    public Initialize2D (int N)
    {   
        System.out.println("N = " +N);
        int counter = 0;
        aTwoD = new int[N][N];

        int i = 1;
        while( i <= N ) 
        {
            int j = 1;
            while( j <= N )
            {
                System.out.println("counter = " +counter);
                aTwoD[i][j] = 0;
                System.out.println("aTwoD["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + aTwoD[i][j]);
                j++;
                counter++;
            }
            i++;
        }  
    }

    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        Initialize2D TwoDArray = new Initialize2D(2);
    }   
}
```

Comment: error i was getting -> N = 2
counter = 0
aTwoD[1][1] = 0
counter = 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Initialize2D.<init>(Initialize2D.java:19)
 at Initialize2D.main(Initialize2D.java:30)

Answer (score 6):

index starts from 0 so `<=` would cause out of bound

Comment: thanks Jigar. This really makes me feel stupid. But what i was trying to do was create an 2D array from aTwoD[1][1] to aTwoD[2][2]. That is why i was using "<=" and N = 2. Is there a special way of doing that ?

Comment: if you specifically want to access [2][2] then you need array to contain 3 elements in both dimensions, change argument so that it creates  `[3][3]`

Comment: Got it JB Nizet. I am very new to programming and i didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you to all of you guys for helping out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Finally, if anyone felt bad that i copied by subsequent question in everyone's response, i again ask for forgiveness. I didn't mean to hurt anyone. Thanks for telling me this thing.

Comment: Np feel free to mark the answer which has answered your question

Answer (score 1):

Array indices in Java start at `0`, and end at `length - 1`. They don't start at `1` and end at `length` as your code assumes.

Comment: thanks Jigar. This really makes me feel stupid. But what i was trying to do was create an 2D array from aTwoD[1][1] to aTwoD[2][2]. That is why i was using "<=" and N = 2. Is there a special way of doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
while( j <= N )
```

to

while( j < N )

In java indexing of N size array goes from 0 to N-1 including.

Comment: thanks Jigar. This really makes me feel stupid. But what i was trying to do was create an 2D array from aTwoD[1][1] to aTwoD[2][2]. That is why i was using "<=" and N = 2. Is there a special way of doing that ?

Comment: @user3043882, if your 2d array has only one element, you declare it aTwoD[1][1] and access as aTwoD[0][0] (it is unique element).

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you iterate over `i` and `j` with the condition `i <= N`, `j <= N`.

Arrays in Java are zero based, meaning that they range between: `0 ... N-1`.
If you access them with `N` that will be out of their range.

Change your iterator from `i <= N` to `i < N` (same for `j`). That should do the trick.

Comment: thanks Jigar. This really makes me feel stupid. But what i was trying to do was create an 2D array from aTwoD[1][1] to aTwoD[2][2]. That is why i was using "<=" and N = 2. Is there a special way of doing that ?